# How to get the reliable current date from win phone disconnected from internet?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am going to develop a service in windows phone to support the subscription for some features. The app should also work offline. I am thinking after doing the purchase and unlock the features, i save date of expiration on the phone (maybe on server as well) and then every time the user load the app current date time will be compared to the expreation date saved on phone, Then the user will be notified if the feature is expired. My question is how can i get the real date while the phone is offline so the user can not cheat it by changing the datetime on the phone.
And Do you guys think it is a smart way to handle the subscription?

Comment: You can't, to my knowledge, use any other reliable systems for getting the current time. For exactly that reason, I'd shy away from using saved expiration times for paid features. I don't have a better solution, but yours will result in a lot of people cheating the system since it's such a well known way to exploit apps.

Comment: To my knowledge, the best way is storing in server. Because even though if the datetime in phone is changed, the server can handled the expiration date and prompt the user for subscription of new feature. Do you got it ???

Comment: @Vijay.P That's good if the app is always online, but there's a focus on offline usage here. What about saving the first-launch date and time somewhere, and if it is changed to an earlier date (e.g. October 12, 2012 to October 12, 2011) then you can know the user has changed its date. No the best way out there, unless you do have online access to a server.

Comment: @Vijay: That works if the app run online not in my case.

Comment: @Harush: thanks for your suggestion i think it can make it secure to some level.

Comment: I think the real question is: is your content so valuable that the user will bother changing the date of his phone (and therefore mess up his mails and appointments) every time he wants to enjoy it? Make sure that you're not putting a protection that will cause more trouble to honest users than to cheaters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in-app purchase for your subscription stuff, then all you need to do is just check the licenses:

```
CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses
```

You need to find the one with `ProductId == "given id"` and check if `IsActive == true`. If the subscription expires it will automatically become inactive. Though, as you correctly guessed, if the device is not connected to network LicenseInformation will be based only on local device time, but this is still a better approach, since you don't need to take care of comparing the date and time all the time.